# Uncaught TypeError: "#submitRates".click is not a functio

Tags: jquery

I cant understand why I'm getting the following error:
"Uncaught TypeError: "#submitRates".click is not a function"

My code looks:

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">        
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>      

 <p id="pQs" >  
    <form>          
        <br>
        <button id="submitRates"> Submit </button>      
    </form>  
 </p>

 <p id="top10">
    <ol>    
    </ol>
 </p>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        ("#submitRates").click(function(){
        });
    });
 </script>

</html>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Should be $("#submitRates") I suspect (the $ is missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the symbol $ before the selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitRates").click(function(){
    });
});
```